# airflow dag failed... but all tasks succeeded

Tags: python, airflow

I am extremely confused by something in our airflow ui. In the tree view (and the graph view), a dag is indicated to have failed. However, all of its member tasks appear to have succeeded. You can see it here below (third from the end):

[image]

Does anyone know how this is possible, what it means, or how one would investigate it?

Comment: Have you checked the tables in db as well?

Comment: What would I be looking for?

Comment: Depending on airflow versions you can look into task_instance,dag_run,task_fail table to debug.

Comment: Has the DAG been updated at all (removed tasks)?

Comment: Did someone perhaps mark the tasks as successful after the failure?

Comment: all good questions but I'm not sure of the answer. Going to have to leave this one as a mystery

Answer (score 10):

I have experienced the same. All tasks complete with success, but the DAG fails. Did not find anything in any logs.

In my case, it was the DAG's dagrun_timeout setting that was set too low for my tasks that did run for more than 30 minutes:

```
dag = DAG(...,
          dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=30),
          ...)
```

I am on Airflow version 1.10.1.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the timeout of the DAG here and work well too